# How to get first day of month/year etc?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, date, dynamic-linq

I'm using `Linq.Dynamic` to query a `SQL Server` database.

I have a date field named 'EnteredOn' which I need to convert to first second of that month (or year, minute etc)

I tried basically everything, but everything throws an error

Here are some of my trials

```
Return $"DateTime({FieldName}.Year,1,1)"
Return $"DateTime({FieldName}.Year,{FieldName}.Month,1)"
Return $"DateTime({FieldName}.Year,{FieldName}.Month,{FieldName}.Day)"
Return $"DateAndTime.DateDiff(2, 0, {FieldName})"
Return $"EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime({FieldName}.Year,{FieldName}.Month,{FieldName}.Day,0,0,0)"
Return $"DbFunctions.CreateDateTime({FieldName}.Year,{FieldName}.Month,{FieldName}.Day,0,0,0)"
```

Either I get an error that I can only use parameterless constructors (so first 3 dont work), or that no such property or field exists (DateDiff), or it doesnt recognize the Class

How can this be done?

Some of the error messages

> No applicable method 'DateDiff' exists in type 'viwAttendancePre'
>   No property or field 'Microsoft' exists in type 'viwAttendancePre'
>   No property or field 'Month' exists in type 'viwAttendancePre'
>   LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] CreateDateTime(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
>   No applicable method 'CreateDateTime' exists in type 'EntityFunctions'
>   No property or field 'DbFunctions' exists in type 'viwAttendancePre'
>   Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   No applicable method 'Date' exists in type 'viwAttendancePre'

**Environment**

Linq Package

```
 <Reference Include="System.Linq.Dynamic, Version=1.0.6132.35681, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<HintPath>..\..\_packages\System.Linq.Dynamic.1.0.7\lib\net40\System.Linq.Dynamic.dll</HintPath>
<Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

**UPDATE** -Using `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`

I see know that if i don't use the fields in the query it does work as follows

```
Dim d = GetSystemContext()
Dim goodq = d.Set(GetType(Attendance)).AsQueryable.Select("new (DateTime(2000,1,1) as mydate)")' this returns just fine
Dim badq = d.Set(GetType(Attendance)).AsQueryable.Select("new (DateTime(AddedOn.Year,1,1) as mydate)")' this throws "System.NotSupportedException: 'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.'"
```

Comment: Which Dynamic LINQ package are you using?

Comment: @IvanStoev, Just added the version to the post. Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing it with [EntityFramework.DynamicLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicLinq) and use the last trial (with `DbFunctions.CreateDateTime`).

Comment: Is it impossible with Microsofts versions/tools? I'd rather not tie myself to 3rd party dlls, if not critical

Comment: The one you are using is not really Microsoft (or at least is not maintained by Microsoft). And the problem is that it doesn't support static methods of "unknown" classes like `DbFunctions`, which in turn is required by EF6. The one I'm suggesting supports that, and also is listed under [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#microsoftentityframeworkcoredynamiclinq) by Microsoft, so I guess it's ok to use it. Other option is to take the one you are using as source code and modify it to support `DbFunctions`, but that sounds harder to me.

Comment: Third option is to use `DateTime` constructors and postprocess the query expression tree with custom `ExpressionVisitor` and replace the `DateTime` constructors with the `DbFunctions.CreateTime` method call. Which also is not trivial. Using the 3rd party package seems the easier solution to me :)

Comment: ok. will it support all the code ive been using till today with system.linq.dynamic? or will i start getting bugs all over?

Comment: This is something I can't answer - I just verified that it solves the concrete issue in question. The decision and associated risks are up to you.

Comment: I tried. It seems it doesn't support basic stuff like `OrderBy` etc, when used with `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core).

## EFCore

```cs
void Main()
{
    var r = Reservations.Select("DateTime(CheckinDate.Year,1,1)");
    r.Dump();
}
```

### EFCore Result

[image]

### EFCore Generated SQL

[image]

## EF 6

For Entity Framework 6, you need to use:

```cs
var datesDynamic = ctx.Reservations.Select("DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(CheckinDate.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)");
```

Note that you need to provide all parameters to the `CreateDateTime` method.

Comment: Hi Stef, and thanks for posting. I tried switching to `Core`, but as i wrote previously, All `IEnumerable` functions now disappear, so my project has now a billion compile errors. How can I have `Core` work also with `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Ok. For now, I moved everything to `AsQueryable` just so I can compile. But I still get the error `System.NotSupportedException: 'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.''`. Here's my syntax: `New (DateTime(EnteredOn.Year,EnteredOn.Month,EnteredOn.Day) AS EnteredOn_Day,ID)`

Comment: Hi, I might have made a drop of progress. I've updated my post. Thanks

Comment: I see. But what's the difference? How come my code is not working? What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I see that you're using `EntityFrameworkCore`, is that a requirement here? As my code is based on standard `EntityFramework` 6.2.

Comment: That was it! `DbFunctions.CreateDateTime`. (Actually, a colleague of mine pointed me to the same solution, but thanks anyhow!!). For posterity: all those zeroes are mandatory. took me some time to get that...:-)